# next/image loaderFile but fallback to default optimized loader

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-image

We serve some images using Imgix so we wanted to set a global [`loaderFile`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/images#imgix) that can deal with those images as per [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/images#imgix). But other images on our app don't use Imgix, in that case we still want to use the built-in Image Optimization API.

next.config.js:

```
images: { 
 loader: 'custom',
 loaderFile: './.loaders/customImageLoader.js',
},
```

customImageLoader.js:

```
export default function ({ src, width, quality }) {
  if (!src.contains(IMGIX_DOMAIN)) return src;

  const url = new URL(src);
  const params = url.searchParams;
  params.set('auto', params.getAll('auto').join(',') || 'format');
  params.set('fit', params.get('fit') || 'max');
  params.set('w', params.get('w') || width.toString());
  params.set('q', quality.toString() || '50');
  return url.href;
}
```

Here `if (!src.contains(IMGIX_DOMAIN)) return src;` it should apply the built-in Image Optimization API, like calling "super()".
Is that possible?